# jQuery Ancestor Listener

Tags: jquery

How to fire an event when an ancestor of an element is removed or no longer displayed in the document?

Thanks

Comment: There is an DOMNodeRemoved event, but it's not x-browser compatible.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ancestor of an element is removed, then the DOM subtree is also removed.

- In this case you don't have elements to fire because they are gone

If the ancestor is invisible then DOM subtree is also invisible.

- In this case ele you have to go there by the id `$("#undisplayed_element_id")`

I think there is no command like this though:

```
 $("#the_id").hey_im_going_to_vanish(function()...)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no event to be triggered when an element is removed. However, you can make a check if element is not present, perform some action, for example:

```
if (! $('#element_id_here').get(0))
{
   // your code here
}
```